# angular 6 : how to loop the server data into ag-Grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ag-grid

i have question i'm new at angular 6 and i face a problem ag-Grid about i want to for loop the rows so i can display all the information that comes from API in the correct column order but the data looping and display the last row only . all i need away to for loop the data and display it in the row , i tried my way to display the data but it display the last row of given data .

here some of my code :-

[MY CODES](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfdcbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
/

thank you and Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the data from API i.e. it is an Observable instead of a hard-coded array, use the `async` pipe with `rowData`:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData | async"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    rowSelection="multiple"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: i just tried it and it gave me like this *ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'*

Comment: Can you please share the code which you you are using to get the rowData from API? You may get this error if you apply the async pipe to a regular Angular object.

Comment: hello Yasir i did shared some of my code and similar to it

Comment: they said you have to convert the the result from array to observable object

Comment: Yes, you can convert it to observable like:

this.rowData = Observable.of(this.rowData);

Make sure you have installed rxjs and imported it:
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

Comment: i did  convert it and gave me an error *ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null*

Comment: Check if you have imported CommonModule in your module:

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ]
})

Comment: i did and still didn't the same issue